# How to determine the worst case complexity of methods in HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, runtime, time-complexity

```
public void addOccurence(String word) { 
    if (hm.containsKey(word)){
          hm.put(word, hm.get(word)+1);
    }
    else {hm.put(word, 1); }
}
```

I know that in average `put(k,v)` and `get(v)` take `o(1)` and their worst cases are `o(n)`. What about `containsKey(v)`? 
And how to determine the running time of things like:

```
hm.put(word, hm.get(word)+1)
```

Is it `o(n^2)` in worst case and `o(1)` in average?

Comment: O(2*n) = O(n). A constant multiplier has no effect on big-O asymptotics. (Also, don't you mean "worst cases" in the first paragraph, rather than "word cases"?)

Comment: check this to be aware of java8+
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923251/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-hashmap-containskey-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Worst case time complexity of `hm.put(word, hm.get(word)+1)` is `O(N)`.**

**How:** suppose you due to excessive collision you hashMap turned into a linked list. So `get()` will have to search the whole linked list hence `O(N)`. Similarly `hm.put()` will need to traverse the linked list to insert the value. So `O(N)+O(N) = O(2N) ~ = O(N)`.

Even though for an insert you will not traverse the whole linked list then also the `get()` method's time complexity is `O(N)`. So total is `O(N)`. So in both cases, the worst-case time complexity is `O(N)`.

This is different in Java-8 as it converts the link list to a tree if the bucket becomes larger than `TREEIFY_THRESHOLD`.

**But asymptotic lower bound of the same is `O(1)`.**

**How:**
Because if your keys are well distributed then the `get()` will have `o(1)` time complexity and same for `insert` also. So resulting in `O(1)` in asymptotic time complexity.

Comment: Thanks! that makes much more sense to me

Comment: from java8+ this rule is not correct: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43911369/hashmap-java-8-implementation

Answer (score 1):

It is at worst *O(N).* You are doing either two or three operations, each of which is at worst *O(N),* so you have *3N* which is still *O(N).* You aren't doing anything of a quadratic nature.

Answer (score 1):

O(N) is not the worst case. HashMap is only claimed to have constant work time. In fact its not true. Constant work time is maintained by usual rehashing of a Map when a special threshold exceeds. Have a look at internal HashMap method:

```
void addEntry(int hash, K key, V value, int bucketIndex) {
    if ((size >= threshold) && (null != table[bucketIndex])) {
        resize(2 * table.length);
        hash = (null != key) ? hash(key) : 0;
        bucketIndex = indexFor(hash, table.length);
    }

    createEntry(hash, key, value, bucketIndex);
}
```

If size is greater than threshold complete rehashing happens, its complexity is equal to creating new HashMap. So the worst case is

> O(new HashMap(oldMap)) + O(N)

O(N) might happen if you have overridden hashCode() function badly, so that it has pure distribution. With default implementations this cant happen. The only danger is in rehashing.

Answer (score 0):

The worst case runtime is not `O(n^2)` because the you do NOT have nested loops with `O(n)` RT for each loop.  The runtime would be O(n) because the you are adding the RT from the `hm.put(word, hm.get(word)+1)` method to the RT from the `hm.containsKey(word)` method.  And `O(n) + O(n) = O(2n)` ==> `O(n)`

The best case would of course be if the string was not in the hashmap and the `else(...)` statement was executed, or `O(1)`.

```
public void addOccurence(String word) { 
    if (hm.containsKey(word)){ //Worst Case O(n)
        hm.put(word, hm.get(word)+1); //Worst case O(n)
    }
    else {hm.put(word, 1); }  //O(1) Runtime
}
```

As a side note, the `containsKey(k)` method is basically a `get(k)` method that returns a boolean based on whether or not the key is there.  On the other hand, the `get(k)` method would actually return the value of the key, assuming the key exists in the hashmap.  The runtimes for both would be the same because they essentially searching through the hashmap in the same way.