# HashMap has backing array, then why is it unordered

Tags: java, arrays, collections, hashmap

I read that HashMap has a backing array, where entries are stored (marked with bucket number, initial size 16). Arrays are ordered, and I can call get(n) to get the element at nth position. Then why is HashMap unordered and has no get(n) method?

Comment: "and has no get(n) method" how exactly do you expect `get(n)` to work/return? Bucket can hold many elements with *similar* hash property (here lets say that keys with same result of `key.hashcode%16` will go to same bucket). Anyway map are ordered but not in a way which we can rely on, since it can change based on amount of elements (to better balance elements in buckets).

Comment: Just as a comment, if you like to maintain **insertion-order** and also use a `HashSet` than you might find the class `LinkedHashSet` useful which does exactly that by adding two pointers **prev** and **next** to each element (a technique called *linked list*).

Comment: The same also holds for `HashMap`, their is a class called `LinkedHashMap` that does the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on your view of what *ordered* means.

Indeed `HashMaps`s internally use an array or another collection that **has a fixed ordering**. However the order has **nothing** to do with insertion order or something like that. The elements are *ordered*, for example, in increasing size of their **hash-values** and they have nothing to do with some actual ordering on the elements themselves.

So `HashMap`s indeed have something like a `get(n)` method if you think of `n` being the **hash-value** of the key-element. The method is called `get(*key*)` and it first computes the **hash-value** of the given key-element and then looks the value up on the internal structure by using `get(*hash-value*)` on it.

Here is an image a quick search yield that shows the structure of `HashSet`s:

[image: HashSet structure]

Note that `HashSet`s are kinda the same than `HashMaps`, they use the same technique and the same image applies. But instead of just inserting an element a map inserts a container that is identified by the key and additionally holds a value.

---

Just as a small overview. A hash-function is a function that given an object computes a small value, the **hash-value** out of it, using its properties. The computation usually can be done fast and a lookup on the internal array at the position given by the hash-value is thus also fast.

To your specific question, as an user of a `HashMap` you generally are not interested in what elements specifically hide behind hash-value `1` or `2` and so on, that is why they did not include such a method. However if you truly need to do that for a special application or so than you can always try to use **Reflection** to access the internals of your `HashMap` or you could also just write a small wrapper around the class that provides such a method.

Comment: Oh, thanks for mentioning that, totally missed it! However the technique itself remains the same.

Comment: Indeed. I have edited the answer. Otherwise it could confuse OP. However the only difference between them is that `HashSet` just stores elements and `HashMap` stores containers, not a big difference.

Comment: There is no difference at all. `HashSet<Foo>` is fundamentally just a `HashMap<Foo, Flag>`

Answer (score 3):

A `HashMap` is divided into individual buckets. Buckets are initially backed by an array, however if the buckets get too large then they are converted to tree structures which are sorted based on hash codes. That fact alone destroys any guarantee it could make about preserving insertion order.

If you'd like to know more about how it's implemented, you can look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43911369/hashmap-java-8-implementation/43911638#43911638) to this question: [HashMap Java 8 implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43911369/hashmap-java-8-implementation/43911638)