# Unique Id for java object for 100% collision free storage in a data structure

Tags: java

I have a method that checks if two objects are equal(by reference).

```
public boolean isUnique( T uniqueIdOfFirstObject, T uniqueIdOfSecondObject ) {
    return (uniqueIdOfFirstObject ==  uniqueIdOfSecondObject);
}
```

(Use case) Assuming that I don't have any control over creation of the object.
I have a method

```
void currentNodeExistOrAddToHashSet(Object newObject, HashSet<T> objectHash) {
    // will it be 100% precise? Assuming both object have the same field values.
    if(!objectHash.contains(newObject){
        objectHash.add(newObject);
    }
}
```

or I could do something like this

```
void currentNodeExistOrAddToHashSet(Object newObject, HashSet<T> objectHash){
    //as per my knowledge, there might be collision for different objects.
    int uniqueId =  System.identityHashCode(newObject);
    if(!objectHash.contains(uniqueId){
        objectHash.add(uniqueId);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to get a 100% collision proof Id in java i.e different object having different IDs, the same object having same ids irrespective of the content of the object?

Comment: `int` is bounded by 32 bit in Java. so technically answer is **No**

Comment: **`UUID`** is possible.However I doubt your requirement is really needed, as it is not giving better performance.

Comment: For your example you just need to implement `equals` properly. Why do you need an id?

Comment: @JigarJoshi Any other primitive data type or data structure is fine.

Comment: @JoopEggen It for a theoretical purpose. I want to understand if it can be done irrespective of the performance. If not. why? If yes. How? What the closest solution to this problem?

Comment: I subscribe to the UUID idea. It's 99.999999999% collision proof.

Comment: @JoopEggen I haven't research on UUID, but thank you. I will take a look into it.

Comment: @JoopEggen of course `UUID` is *better*, but using a `HashSet` still bounds this to 32 bits - as opposed to 128 that UUID has

Comment: @algrid I participated in an online coding contest. My apology that  I am unable to reproduce the same problem. If I could somehow get a 100% collision proof solution. I could have solved that problem in o(n).

Comment: Either you're looking for guaranteed generic lossless compression, which is impossible by [the pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), or it's simply converting data to a set of types of the same size or larger, which is easy enough. Or you may just be misunderstanding how hash-sets work - they are designed to differentiate between non-equal objects with the same hash.

Comment: There is no sense in doing `if(!objectHash.contains(newObject){objectHash.add(newObject);}`. It’s already the contract of `Set.add` to only add the element if not being in the set. It even returns a `boolean` telling you whether it has been added. So you can simply use `objectHash.add(newObject);`, doubling your performance.

Comment: @Dukeling: perhaps, he’s just looking for [`IdentityHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/IdentityHashMap.html)…

Answer (score 1):

Since you put them into a `HashSet` that uses hashcode/equals and hashCode is `32 bits` long - this has *a limit*; thus collision will happen. Especially since a `HashSet` actually only cares about n-last bits before making itself bigger in size and thus adding one more bit and so on. You can read a lot more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43911369/hashmap-java-8-implementation/43924719#43924719) for example.

The question is different here: why you want a collision free structure in the first place? If you define a fairly well distributed `hashCode` and a fairly decent `equals` - these things should not matter to you at all. If you worry about performance of a search, it is `O(1)` for `HashSet`.

You could define hashCode and equality based on `UUID`, like let's say `UUID#randomUUID` - but this *still* bounds your hashCode to the same 32-bits, thus collision could still happen.

Comment: I will read about it. I can create a custom data structure. Irrespective of the performance, I am interested in knowing is it possible, at least theoretically?

Comment: @SharukAhmed as long as you them to be a `Set` structure - no; all of them use hashcode that is 32 bits (int) long.