# Map.ofEntries gives Null Pointer Exception on checking NULL key using containsKey()

Tags: java, collections, java-8, nullpointerexception

I was fetching key from a constant map earlier using HashMap.

On passing a **NULL key** at `containsKey()`, I used to get **FALSE**.

To make the code look fancy, I tried java-8 over it. So, instead of HashMap, *I started using Map.ofEntries* to build my map

Surprisingly, I got **Null Pointer Exception** when a Null key was passed to `containsKey()` method

```
String str = null;

Map<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
hashMap.put("k1", "v1");
System.out.print(hashMap.containsKey(str)); // This gives false

Map<String,String> ofEntriesMap = Map.ofEntries( Map.entry("k1", "v1")); 
System.out.print(ofEntriesMap.containsKey(str)); // Why this gives Null Pointer Exception ?
```

I am unable to figure out, why it is behaving differently at `Map.ofEntries`.

What is the best way to handle this situation ?

Comment: `Map` implementations have the choice whether to support null keys and values. This is probably a design flaw, but it's the spec, so if you have just `Map`, you don't know whether it will support them.

Comment: Making the code look fancy is a poor reason for any change, especially to code that already works.  Making it *clearer* or *easier to read* would be a different story.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The javadoc of [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#unmodifiable) says:

> #### Unmodifiable Maps
>
> The [`Map.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#of()), [`Map.ofEntries`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#ofEntries(java.util.Map.Entry...)), and [`Map.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#copyOf(java.util.Map)) static factory methods provide a convenient way to create unmodifiable maps. The Map instances created by these methods have the following characteristics:
>
> - They are [*unmodifiable*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#unmodifiable). Keys and values cannot be added, removed, or updated. Calling any mutator method on the Map will always cause `UnsupportedOperationException` to be thrown. However, if the contained keys or values are themselves mutable, this may cause the Map to behave inconsistently or its contents to appear to change.
> - **They disallow `null` keys and values**. Attempts to create them with `null` keys or values result in `NullPointerException`.
> - ...

In contrast, the javadoc of [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html) says:

> Hash table based implementation of the `Map` interface. This implementation provides all of the optional map operations, and **permits `null` values and the `null` key**. (The `HashMap` class is roughly equivalent to `Hashtable`, except that it is unsynchronized and permits nulls.) This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.
>
> ...

Comment: That the map in question does not permit null keys makes it *allowable* for that map's `containsKey()` method to throw an NPE when a null argument is presented, but does not require it to do so.  Thus, the situation is a little more nuanced than this answer seems to suggest.

Answer (score 3):

> instead of HashMap, *I started using Map.ofEntries* to build my map
>
> Surprisingly, I got **Null Pointer Exception** when a Null key was passed
> to containsKey() method

The documentation for [`java.util.Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#unmodifiable) says, in part:

> **Some map implementations have restrictions on the keys and values they may contain**. For example, some implementations prohibit null
> keys and values, and some have restrictions on the types of their
> keys. Attempting to insert an ineligible key or value throws an
> unchecked exception, typically `NullPointerException` or
> `ClassCastException`. **Attempting to query the presence of an
> ineligible key or value may throw an exception**, or it may simply
> return false; some implementations will exhibit the former behavior
> and some will exhibit the latter.

(Emphasis added.)

As [@Andreas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68581152/2402272) already observes, the maps created via `Map.ofEntries()` are of such an implementation.  Specifically, they disallow null keys and values.  Although it is not documented whether their `containsKey()` methods exercise the option to throw when presented with a null argument, you need to use them with that possibility in mind.

On the other hand, as Andreas also shows, `HashMap` is documented to permit null keys and values, so its `containsKey()` method is expected to complete normally when passed a null argument.

> What is the best way to handle this situation ?

You have two main choices:

- If you want to continue to (directly) use a map created via `Map.ofEntries()` then you must avoid testing whether it contains null keys.  Since you know that it *cannot* contain null keys, such tests are unnecessary.
- If you want to rely on being able to test null keys' presence in your map, and especially if you want the option of having null keys or null values in it, then you must not use `Map.ofEntries()` to create it.  You might, however, use `Map.ofEntries()` to *initialize* it.  For example:

  ```
  Map<String, String> myMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(
      new HashMap<String, String>(
          Map.ofEntries(
              Map.Entry("k1", "v1")
          )
      )
  );
  ```

  Note also that if you are putting fewer than 11 entries in your map, then `Map.of()` is a bit tidier than `Map.ofEntries()`.  And, of course, if you don't care whether the map is modifiable then you don't have to put it into that unmodifiable wrapper.

Comment: LOL!! Taking an unmodifiable map, making it modifiable, just to make it unmodifiable again. Sorry, it works for the task at hand (+1), it just struck my funny bone.

Comment: Of course, instead of `Map.ofEntries( Map.entry("k1", "v1") )` you can simply write `Map.of("k1", "v1")` and instead of `Collections.unmodifiableMap( new HashMap<String, String>( Map.of("k1", "v1") ) )` you can use `Collections.singletonMap("k1", "v1")`

Comment: Indeed yes, @Holger, as this answer already mentions, albeit without example code.  I demonstrate `Map.ofEntries()` because the OP asks specifically about that.  And if the OP's real code needs to set up a map with more than ten entries then `Map.of()` is not a viable option there.

Answer (score 2):

This is implementation detail of the unmodifiable map, created by `Map.ofEntries`.

When you're adding `null` key to `HashMap`, it calculates hash of `null` equal to `0`.

```
static final int hash(Object key) {
    int h;
    return (key == null) ? 0 : (h = key.hashCode()) ^ (h >>> 16);
}
```

But `Map.ofEntries` creates `ImmutableCollections.Map1` in case when only one pair was provided and `ImmutableCollections.MapN` otherwise.

Here is implementation of `ImmutableCollections.Map1::containsKey`

```
public boolean containsKey(Object o) {
    return o.equals(k0); // implicit nullcheck of o
}
```

You can see that comment says that `NullPointerException` is expected behaviour. As for `ImmutableCollections.MapN::containsKey` it uses explicit null-check.

```
public boolean containsKey(Object o) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(o);
        return size > 0 && probe(o) >= 0;
}
```

If you refer `Map::containsKey` Javadoc, you can see that it's explicitly said that this method may or may not produce NPE.

> Returns true if this map contains a mapping for the specified key. More
> formally, returns true if and only if this map contains a mapping for a key k such that Objects.equals(key, k). (There can be at most one such mapping.)
>
> Params:
> key – key whose presence in this map is to be tested
>
> Returns:
> true if this map contains a mapping for the specified key
>
> Throws:
> ClassCastException – if the key is of an inappropriate type for this map (optional)
>
> NullPointerException – if the specified key is null and this map does not permit null keys (optional)

Comment: No, it is not an implementation detail, it is a specification, i.e. it is documented in the javadoc of `Map`.

Comment: I would say that `Map`s javadoc allows some ambiguity and it's for every implementation to decide what to do. So, I consider this as an implementation detail

Comment: I'm referring only to javadoc of `Map::containsKey`. Javadoc of `Map` says that `Map.of`, `Map.ofEntries`, and `Map.copyOf` are return unmodifiable map, which is required to return NPE, there is no ambiguity for those, but in *general*  `Map::containsKey`'s javadoc allows ambiguity.

Comment: I do (still) think that calling it an implementation detail is misleading, but upon further review, I find that the fact that the `Map` provided by `Map.ofEntries()` does not allow null keys does not require that its `containsKey()` method throw an NPE when a null argument is presented.  It still has the option of returning `false`.  Follow the link in the JavaDocs to the meaning of "optional" as it is used there.

Comment: @JohnBollinger it can be called an implementation detail since method `void test(Map<?,?> m) { m.containsKey(null); }` may or may not produce NPE depending on *implementation* of `Map`. Javadoc of `containsKey` doesn't say in what cases NPE is produced, so result of this operation is defined by implementation of `Map`. And both NPE and true/false are allowed by method's contract.

Comment: @geobreze, I acknowledge that there is an argument that can be made for calling it an implementation detail.  That does not mean that using that description is not misleading.  "Implementation detail" suggests (to me) something that is altogether undocumented, which users of the class don't need to know about and should not care about.  None of those apply in this case.

Comment: @JohnBollinger implementation details may be documented too. The question was "why it is behaving differently at Map.ofEntries" and I find an answer "because of different implementation" reasonable.

Comment: @geobreze, I, too, find the answer "because of different implementation" reasonable (though rather bare boned by itself). Perhaps changing to that wording would improve this answer, then.

Comment: @geobreze Interesting code you have put for passing ```NULL to hash() method```. That it is changing ```NULL key to 0```. So would that mean if I then add a ```key as integer 0```,  this would replace the NULL key value ??? hmm.. let me try this

Comment: @geobreze I tried.. Null key and 0 Key both entered map without Replace. So they must be at same Bucket coz of same Hash!!! Please validate y supposition

Comment: @AdityaRewari hashmap doesn't use hashcode only. You're right `null` and `0` have the same hashcode of `0` which means that they will be placed in the same bucket. But `null` and `0` are not equal. When not equal objects have the same hash it's called a collision. There are different types of collision resolution, but `java.util.HashMap` uses separate chaining. You can add as many items as you want with a hash equal to 0, they will be placed in the same bucket and this bucked will contain a linked list (or binary tree) of items you've added. More: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43911638/4655217