# How can I improve the efficiency and/or performance of my relatively simple Java counting method?

Tags: java, performance, methods, classification, word-count

I'm building a classifier which has to read through a lot of textdocuments, but I found out that my `countWordFrequenties` method gets slower the more documents it has processed. This method underneath takes 60ms (on my PC), while reading, normalizing, tokenizing, updating my vocabulary and equalizing of different lists of integers only takes 3-5ms in total (on my PC). My `countWordFrequencies` method is as follows:

```
public List<Integer> countWordFrequencies(String[] tokens) 
{
    List<Integer> wordFreqs = new ArrayList<>(vocabulary.size());
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < vocabulary.size(); i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < tokens.length; j++)
            if (tokens[j].equals(vocabulary.get(i)))
                counter++;

        wordFreqs.add(i, counter);
        counter = 0;
    }

    return wordFreqs;
}
```

What is the best way for me to speed this process up? What is the problem of this method?

This is my entire Class, there is another Class Category, is it a good idea to post this also here or don't you guys need it?

```
public class BayesianClassifier 
{
    private Map<String,Integer>  vocabularyWordFrequencies;
    private List<String> vocabulary;
    private List<Category> categories;
    private List<Integer> wordFrequencies;
    private int trainTextAmount;
    private int testTextAmount;
    private GUI gui;

    public BayesianClassifier() 
    {
        this.vocabulary = new ArrayList<>();
        this.categories = new ArrayList<>();
        this.wordFrequencies = new ArrayList<>();
        this.trainTextAmount = 0;
        this.gui = new GUI(this);
        this.testTextAmount = 0;
    }

    public List<Category> getCategories() 
    {
        return categories;
    }

    public List<String> getVocabulary() 
    {
        return this.vocabulary;
    }

    public List<Integer> getWordFrequencies() 
    {
        return  wordFrequencies;
    }

    public int getTextAmount() 
    {
        return testTextAmount + trainTextAmount;
    }

    public void updateWordFrequency(int index, Integer frequency)
    {
        equalizeIntList(wordFrequencies);
        this.wordFrequencies.set(index, wordFrequencies.get(index) + frequency);
    }

    public String readText(String path) 
    {
        BufferedReader br;
        String result = "";

        try 
        {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) 
            {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append("\n");
                line = br.readLine();
            }

            result = sb.toString();
            br.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }

    public String normalizeText(String text) 
    {
        String fstNormalized = Normalizer.normalize(text, Normalizer.Form.NFD);

        fstNormalized = fstNormalized.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]","");
        fstNormalized = fstNormalized.toLowerCase();
        fstNormalized = fstNormalized.replace("\n","");
        fstNormalized = fstNormalized.replaceAll("[0-9]","");
        fstNormalized = fstNormalized.replaceAll("[/()!?;:,.%-]","");
        fstNormalized = fstNormalized.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ");

        return fstNormalized;
    }

    public String[] handleText(String path) 
    {
        String text = readText(path);
        String normalizedText = normalizeText(text);

        return tokenizeText(normalizedText);
    }

    public void createCategory(String name, BayesianClassifier bc) 
    {
        Category newCategory = new Category(name, bc);

        categories.add(newCategory);
    }

    public List<String> updateVocabulary(String[] tokens) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
            if (!vocabulary.contains(tokens[i]))
                vocabulary.add(tokens[i]);

        return vocabulary;
    }

    public List<Integer> countWordFrequencies(String[] tokens)
    {
        List<Integer> wordFreqs = new ArrayList<>(vocabulary.size());
        int counter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < vocabulary.size(); i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < tokens.length; j++)
                if (tokens[j].equals(vocabulary.get(i)))
                    counter++;

            wordFreqs.add(i, counter);
            counter = 0;
        }

        return wordFreqs;
    }

    public String[] tokenizeText(String normalizedText) 
    {
        return normalizedText.split(" ");
    }

    public void handleTrainDirectory(String folderPath, Category category) 
    {
        File folder = new File(folderPath);
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        if (listOfFiles != null) 
        {
            for (File file : listOfFiles) 
            {
                if (file.isFile()) 
                {
                    handleTrainText(file.getPath(), category);
                }
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("There are no files in the given folder" + " " + folderPath.toString());
        }
    }

    public void handleTrainText(String path, Category category) 
    {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        trainTextAmount++;

        String[] text = handleText(path);

        updateVocabulary(text);
        equalizeAllLists();

        List<Integer> wordFrequencies = countWordFrequencies(text);
        long finishTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("That took 1: " + (finishTime-startTime)+ " ms");

        long startTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        category.update(wordFrequencies);
        updatePriors();

        long finishTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("That took 2: " + (finishTime2-startTime2)+ " ms");
    }

    public void handleTestText(String path) 
    {
        testTextAmount++;

        String[] text = handleText(path);
        List<Integer> wordFrequencies = countWordFrequencies(text);
        Category category = guessCategory(wordFrequencies);
        boolean correct = gui.askFeedback(path, category);

        if (correct) 
        {
            category.update(wordFrequencies);
            updatePriors();
            System.out.println("Kijk eens aan! De tekst is succesvol verwerkt.");
        } 
        else 
        {
            Category correctCategory = gui.askCategory();
            correctCategory.update(wordFrequencies);
            updatePriors();
            System.out.println("Kijk eens aan! De tekst is succesvol verwerkt.");
        }
    }

    public void updatePriors()
    {
        for (Category category : categories)
        {
            category.updatePrior();
        }
    }

    public Category guessCategory(List<Integer> wordFrequencies) 
    {
        List<Double> chances = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < categories.size(); i++)
        {
            double chance = categories.get(i).getPrior();

            System.out.println("The prior is:" + chance);

            for(int j = 0; j < wordFrequencies.size(); j++)
            {
                chance = chance * categories.get(i).getWordProbabilities().get(j);
            }

            chances.add(chance);
        }

        double max = getMaxValue(chances);
        int index = chances.indexOf(max);

        System.out.println(max);
        System.out.println(index);
        return categories.get(index);
    }

    public double getMaxValue(List<Double> values)
    {
        Double max = 0.0;

        for (Double dubbel : values)
        {
            if(dubbel > max)
            {
                max = dubbel;
            }
        }

        return max;
    }

    public void equalizeAllLists()
    {
        for(Category category : categories)
        {
            if (category.getWordFrequencies().size() < vocabulary.size())
            {
                category.setWordFrequencies(equalizeIntList(category.getWordFrequencies()));
            }
        }

        for(Category category : categories)
        {
            if (category.getWordProbabilities().size() < vocabulary.size())
            {
                category.setWordProbabilities(equalizeDoubleList(category.getWordProbabilities()));
            }
        }
    }

    public List<Integer> equalizeIntList(List<Integer> list)
    {
        while (list.size() < vocabulary.size())
        {
            list.add(0);
        }

        return list;
    }

    public List<Double> equalizeDoubleList(List<Double> list)
    {
        while (list.size() < vocabulary.size())
        {
            list.add(0.0);
        }

        return list;
    }

    public void selectFeatures()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < wordFrequencies.size(); i++)
        {
            if(wordFrequencies.get(i) < 2)
            {
                vocabulary.remove(i);
                wordFrequencies.remove(i);

                for(Category category : categories)
                {
                    category.removeFrequency(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you phrase your question more clearly. What takes 50 ms and what takes 3-5ms is not clear

Comment: Sorry, edit is there, this method takes 50ms to execute for one text, while a set of six other methods only takes 2-3ms (both relatively simple). I know that this one is a bit harder but 50ms looks a bit odd to me.

Comment: This method makes a list of integers of how many times words from my vocabulary appear in the 'tokens' which is a tokenized text.

Comment: Can you show more code. We dont know what vocabulary variable really is

Comment: Everything works but really slow... PS: guys, thanks for your interest, i'm editting this post completely now!

Comment: I misread the code, you're right, it's correct. Strangely programmed, but correct.

Comment: @JBNizet every help is appreciated if you know a better way, i'm just a beginner in Java.

Comment: I think rather than using List for vocabulary, you should use some kind of Set. For example, HashSet<String>. This would be an improvement.

Comment: But the ordering of vocabulary is super important in my code so a Set won't do @vinay.

Comment: The use LinkedHashSet

Comment: The `add(i, counter)` could be replaced by `add(counter)`. You could even use an array of Strings, since you know the size of the list in advance, and it doesn't have to grow dynamically.

Comment: @JBNizet an array of Integers :)

Comment: @v.ladynev of course. It's getting late...

Comment: I'm going to change `vocabulary` and `wordFrequencies` Lists to one `Map<String,Integer>` tomorrow, thanks for your help!

Comment: @TotalCare: you may also benefit from getting your code reviewed on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your method has `O(n*m)` run time ( n being the vocabulary size and m the token size). With hashing this could be reduced to `O(m)` which is clearly better.

```
for (String token: tokens) {
  if(!map.containsKey(token)){
      map.put(token,0);
  }
  map.put(token,map.get(token)+1);
}
```

Comment: Where is a `vocabulary` here? :)

Comment: This is still O(n^2) behind the scenes.

Comment: Check implementation of `containsKey`. Still doing nested looping.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923251/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-hashmap-containskey-in-java

Comment: @Voicu A loop for the worst case.  `containsKey` has `O(1)` complexity

Comment: I really appreciate your help guys, i'm a student in University and i'm highly interested in learning more of how Java works and some performance but two different answers makes me a bit confused. If @Voicu is right, I still don't know what to do. If @ v.ladynev is right I'm going to change my entire project.

Comment: @Voicu, I suggest **you** to check how hash maps work instead. The only case in which O(n^2) may happen is when all the hash codes of all the tokens are the same, which is never a real-world scenario.

Comment: @TotalCare read the question Jake linked.  It's `O(1)` in general, and only `O(n)` in worst-case (bad hashing) scenarios.

Comment: btw chaps, HashMap has O(lgn) in worst-case, because it uses a TreeMap in the case of high collisions

Comment: @user3707125 to nitpick, the hash codes don't need to be the same. Only to lead to the same bucket. But I agree: containsKey() for a HashMap is O(1), and this scenario has almost 0 chance to happen, unless the vocabulary is carefully chosen for this worst case to happen.

Comment: It should be noted that the worst case in this scenario is if every single item stored in the map hashed to the same bucket, I don't know the exact probability of this but it is so unlikely I wouldn't even think about it.

Answer (score 3):

Using a `Map` should dramatically increase performance, as Sleiman Jneidi suggested in his answer. This can be done, however, much more elegantly with Java 8's streaming APIs:

```
Map<String, Long> frequencies = 
    Arrays.stream(tokens)
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), 
                                         Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know about `Function.identity()` - it is a matter of style, though I usually use `UnaryOperator.identity()`. It extends `Function`, so may be used in a context that requires either. For this case, however, it is entirely a matter of opinion.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, what does this exactly do better in comparison to just making a Map<String,Double>?

Comment: @TotalCare do you mean in comparison to building the Map yourself? Mainly the fact that you don't have to. Mainly, it reduces the amount of code you need to write, and allows you on the "business logic" of your code, and offloads the boiler-plated part to the JDK.

Comment: @Mureink why do you use long instead of double?

Comment: Upvoted. An impressive answer for sure, but "concise" and "elegant" are not synonymous :-)

Comment: @TotalCare `Collectors.counting()` returns a long, so I went with it. Besides, a counter cannot be a floating point number, so unless you intend to have more than 2^63-1 occurrences of the same word, there really is no reason to use a double.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a list for the vocabulary, and another one for the frequencies, I'd use a Map that will store word->frequency. That way you can avoid the double loop which in my mind is what kills your performance.

```
public Map<String,Integer> countWordFrequencies(String[] tokens) {
    // vocabulary is Map<String,Integer> initialized with all words as keys and 0 as value
    for (String word: tokens)
      if (vocabulary.containsKey(word)) {
        vocabulary.put(word, vocabulary.get(word)+1);
      }
    return vocabulary;
}
```

Comment: The question doesnt say what is the datatype of vocabulary.

Comment: @vinay - since he uses `get(int)`, I assume it a list of some sort

Comment: @NirLevy I used this, now I want to make also maps of the wordFrequencies and wordProbabilities of category, how do I make a map with all the exact Keys and all values are 0?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use Java 8 stuff you can try to use [`MultiSet`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multiset) from guava

Comment: I do want to use anything there is, what can I use from Java 8 in your opinion?

Comment: @TotalCare Mureinik's [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34500750/3405171) is the best one. It uses Java 8.