# What is the Complexity of this method that makes use of a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, time-complexity

I know that the insertion into a `HashMap` takes **O(1)** time Complexity, so for inserting `n` elements the complexity should be **O(n)**. I have a little doubt about the below method.

*Code:*

```
private static Map<Character, Character> mapCharacters(String message) {
    Map<Character, Character> map = new HashMap<>();
    char idx = 'a';
    for (char ch : message.toCharArray()) { // a loop - O(n)
        if (!map.containsKey(ch)) {         // containsKey - take O(n) to check the whole map
            map.put(ch, idx);
            ++idx;
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

What I am doing is to map the decrypted message with the sequential `"abcd"`.

So, My confusion is whether the complexity of the above method is **O(n^2)** or **O(n)**? Please help me to clear my doubt.

Comment: containsKey is not O(n) fortunately.

Comment: @sp00m - It is complicated ...

Answer (score 2):

It's amortised O(n). `containsKey` and `put` are both amortised O(1); see [What is the time complexity of HashMap.containsKey() in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923251/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-hashmap-containskey-in-java) in particular.

Answer (score 1):

The time complexity of both `containsKey()` and `put()` will depend on the implementation of the `equals/hashCode` contract of the object that is used as a *key*.

Under the hood, `HashMap` maintains an array of buckets. And each *bucket* corresponds to a range of hashes. Each non-empty bucket contains *nodes* (each node contains information related to a particular map-entry) that form either a *linked list* or a *tree* (*since Java 8*).

The process of determining the right *bucket* based on the *hash* of the provided *key* is almost instant, unless the process of computing the *hash* is heavy, but anyway it's considered to have a constant time complexity **O(1)**. Accessing the *bucket* (i.e. accessing array element) is also **O(1)**, but then things can become tricky. Assuming that *bucket* contains only a *few elements*, checking them will not significantly increase the total cost (while performing both  `containsKey()` and `put()` we should check whether provided *key* exists in the *map*) and overall time-complexity will be **O(1)**.

But in the case when **all** the map-entries for some reason ended up in the **same bucket** then iterating over the *linked list* will result in **O(n)**, and if nodes are stored as a Red-black tree the worse case cost of both `containsKey()` and `put()` will be **O(log n)**.

In case `Character` as a *key* we have a proper implementation of the `equals/hashCode`. Proper hash function is important to ensure that objects would be evenly spread among buckets. But if you were using instead a custom object which `hashCode()` is broken, for instance always returning the same number, then all entries will end up in the same bucket and performance will be poor.

*Collisions*, situations when different objects produces hashes in the range that is being mapped to the same bucket, are inevitable, and we need a good hash function to make the number of collisions as fewer as possible, so that bucket would be "evenly" occupied and the map get expanded when the number of non-empty *buckets* exceeds load factor.

The time complexity of this particular method is linear **O(n)**. But it might not be the case if you would change the type of the *key*.

Answer (score 0):

Given your original code below:

```
private static Map<Character,Character> mapCharacters(String message){
    Map<Character, Character> map = new HashMap<>();
    char idx = 'a';
    for (char ch : message.toCharArray()) {
        if (!map.containsKey(ch)) {
            map.put(ch, idx);
            ++idx;
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

Here are some observations about the time complexity:

- Iterating each character in `message` will be O(n) – pretty clearly if there are 10 characters it takes 10 steps, 10,000 characters will take 10,000 steps. The time complexity is directly proportional to `n`.
- Inside the loop, you're checking if the map contains that character already – using `containsKey()`, this is a constant-time operation which is defined as O(1) time complexity. The idea is that the actual time to evaluate the result of `containsKey()` should be the same whether your map has 10 keys or 10,000 keys.
- Inside the `if`, you have `map.put()` which is another constant-time operation, another O(1) operation.
- Combined together: for every `nth` character, you spend time iterating it in the loop, checking if the map has it already, and adding it; all of this would be 3n (three times `n`) which is just O(n).

Separately, you could make a small improvement to your code by replacing this block:

```
if (!map.containsKey(ch)) {
    map.put(ch, idx);
    ++idx;
}
```

with something like below (which retains the same behavior of running `++idx` only if you've put something, and specifically if the previous thing was either "not present" or perhaps had been set with "null" - though the "set as null" doesn't apply from your code sample):

```
Character previousValue = map.putIfAbsent(ch, idx);
if (previousValue == null) {
    ++idx;
}
```

Though the time complexity wouldn't change, using `containsKey()` makes the code clearer, and also takes advantage of well-tested, performant code that's available for free.

Under the covers, calling [`Map.putIfAbsent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-) is implemented like below (as of OpenJDK 17) showing an initial call to `get()` followed by `put()` if the key isn't present.

```
default V putIfAbsent(K key, V value) {
    V v = get(key);
    if (v == null) {
        v = put(key, value);
    }

    return v;
}
```